# multiple errors while compiling simple hello world c++ program in g++ ubuntu

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-14.04

below is my hello world program i have written in nano editor.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main
 {
   cout<< "Hello world";
   return 0;
 }
```

when i compiled it, i got these many errors.

```
ello.cpp:4:5: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
 int main
     ^
hello.cpp:6:22: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘;’ token
  cout<< "Hello world";
                      ^
hello.cpp:6:6: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
  cout<< "Hello world";
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:115:7: note: candidate is: std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::operator void*() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
       operator void*() const
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:115:7: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘void*’ to ‘int’
hello.cpp:7:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
  return 0;
  ^
hello.cpp:8:2: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
  }
```

please help me.

Comment: `int main` you re missing parenthesis: `int main()`

Comment: You need to find a [beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: C++ error messages are carefully engineered to cause maximum confusion for trivial mistakes.

Comment: Also, DO NOT include the entire `std` namespace. `std::cout` is a better way of writing

Comment: thanks a lot guys :). can't believe i did such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the parentheses that mark `main()` as a function:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it's much easier to understand namespaces if you explicitly use `std::cout` and `std::endl` rather than `using` the whole of `namespace std` (which can get you into confusion if you're not clear about what's going on).  Alternatively, at least be clear about what you're `using`:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yep, okey thank you for your remark :) !!